# Getting Item and value from list by Specific Data

Tags: list, splistitem, item, data

I would like getting a specific item from a specific list but i don't have ID, just a field (column) value.

Here's my list:
[image]

On the site, i have only the name...i'd like to recover the paid leave field value.

Here's what i tried to do but...

```
SPWeb thisWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPUser currentUser = thisWeb.CurrentUser;
SPQuery myQuery = new SPQuery();
myQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='User'/>" +
                "<Value Type='Text'>"+ currentUser.Name +"</Value></Eq></Where>";
SPListItemCollection _items = thisWeb.Lists["Sumarry"].GetItems(myQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change your query to:

```
"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='User' />"+
      "<Value Type='User'>"+ currentUser.LoginName +"</Value></Eq></Where>"
```

See the [link](http://www.ashokraja.me/tips/How-to-use-User-Name-User-Id-Logged-in-User-Id-in-SharePoint-CAML-Query) for details

Comment: Thanks...but now how can i get the value of the Paid Leave column?

Comment: SPListItemCollection _items = thisWeb.Lists["Sumarry"].GetItems(myQuery);
_items[0]["Paid Leave"];

Answer (score 0):

**Code to get the data from list using ecma script object model.**

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server" />

<script src="../jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var rowscount = 1;

    function retrieveCurrentListProperties() {
      var  clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        this.web = clientContext.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("News");
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        //var q = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='End_x0020_Date'/><Value Type='DateTime'><Today/></Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
        //var q = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ApprovalStatus'/><Value Type='Text'>Approve</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
        var q = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ApprovalStatus'/><Value Type='Text'>Approve</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>" + rowscount + "</RowLimit></View>";
       // var q = "<View></View>";
        camlQuery.set_viewXml(q);
        this.listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(this.listItems);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));

    }

    function onSuccess(sender, args) {
        //  alert('web title:' + this.list.get_ApprovalStatus() + '\n ID:' + this.list.get_id() + '\n Created Date:' + this.list.get_created());
        // alert("success " + this.listItems.get_id() + "  arbs " + args);

        var linkUrl = "";
        var imageUrl = "";
        var listEnumerator = this.listItems.getEnumerator();
        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
            linkUrl = currentItem.get_item('Title');
           // imageUrl = currentItem.get_item('ImageURL');
           //  document.write('<img src="' + imageUrl + '"+>');
           // alert(linkUrl);
            $('#maindiv').append("<div>" + linkUrl + "</div>");
        }
    }
    function onFail(sender, args) {
        alert('failed to get list. Error:' + args.get_message());
    }

   SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', null, function() {
        retrieveCurrentListProperties();
    });

    function filldata() {
        // alert("called");
        $('#maindiv').empty();
        rowscount = rowscount + 1;
        retrieveCurrentListProperties();
    }
</script>
<input id="Button1" type="button" onclick="filldata()"  value="Loadmore" />
<div id="maindiv">   </div>
```